# Vimeo doesn't show in Firefox 40: TypeError: e._video.currentFile is null

Tags: javascript, firefox, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I embed vimeo video, and get this error in Firefox 40:

```
TypeError: e._video.currentFile is null
```

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/128202299&amp;api=true&amp;callback=embedVimeo"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>

function embedVideo(data) {
  var iframe, player;
  $('#divVideo').html(data.html);
  iframe = $('iframe')[0];
  player = $f(iframe);
  player.api('play');
}
```

Comment: can you create a quick jsfiddle? also is `divVideo` the id of ur `div`? if yes then it should be `$('#divVideo').html(data.html);` notice the **#**

Comment: you there @lavaldi? did you try adding the `#`?

Comment: Hi @Sushil, the '#' is in my code, I forgot to put the copy here. Edited.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: @Sushil, simply enter Vimeo page and appears the error [image](http://i.imgur.com/tVQWyi0.png)

Comment: it works for me in firefox. check this http://imgur.com/NJqGPX6

Comment: were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi @Sushil, I think the problem was my Firefox, did not have the flash player plugin. Another thing I understand is that Vimeo, in Firefox for Linux, called the flash player.

Comment: oh yes. you need the flash player plugin to run videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appears not to have the Flash plugin installed on Firefox because Vimeo only shows Flash Player on Linux and MacOS.